# Nodejs stream video (mp4) and switch audio tracks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mp4

I want to play a video in the browser via nodejs which is on my PC. I do this via express and use this code:

https://medium.com/better-programming/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6 (Scroll to "The Server").

This is exactly what I need but I want to change the audio track. The mp4 file I am accessing has multiple internal audio tracks (multiple languages). As you can see here you can change the audio track with the VLC Media Player. And as the vlc media player can do this i would implement this with nodejs.

Thanks for help!

[image: vlc media player]

Comment: The server just send a stream of the file to the client. You have to select the right audio track on the client side. The server has no influence on the audio track. See @o-jones answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cited some sample server code that delivers a stream containing a `.mp4` object. There's nothing much you can do **server-side** to change the language.

But you can use **client-side Javascript** to [enumerate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) the [audio tracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioTrack) in the stream.

This code, for example, sets `track.enabled` to `true` for the track with the German language, and `track.enabled` to `false` for the rest. That mutes all audio except the German-language track.

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoplayer')
for (let i = 0; i < videoElement.audioTracks.length; i++) {
  const track = videoElement.audioTracks[i]
  track.enabled = (track.language === 'de-DE')
}
```

But you should be careful with this crummy example code; it mutes the entire stream if there's no German track.

Comment: Sadly, that API isn't implemented in most browsers.